# List Item Styling | Added Dynamically | Update Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I have a ul element which I need to add **list item dynamically.** UL element has class name res. I don't want to add class to list item. Is there anyway to **add the list item dynamically without losing the style**..!

```
<ul class="res">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" target="_parent">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="shortcords.html">Short Codes</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a id="login" href="login.html">login</a></li>
    <li><a id="logout">Hello Guest<span class="arrorow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Booking History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT 1: 
I attached a pic here... Please see it carefully.

I added those circled ones dynamically. Please check the styling of that...!
[image]

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking exactly but if you add a new `<li />` to `<ul class="res" />` it will not _lose_ any styles applied from CSS assuming there are any (what is "the style" that you are referring to?). Do you have a demo that recreates your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
$('.res').append('<li><a href="/location">Location</a></li>')
```

this resolved the issue...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ELEMENT NAME` to style it without the need of adding class to each element.

For example:

```
ul.res li {
    color: red;
}
```

The above code will apply color red to all `li` elements inside `ul` with class `res`.

Comment: Please check the post..!

Comment: I'll try and will let you know soon :)

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad! That's not the problem here...!